# pptpd dead but subsys locked? on cent os

Tags: centos, iptables, vpn, pptp

i install point to point tunnel (PPTP) in my VPS. (Cent OS 6 64 Bit)

everything fine after reboot the PPTP not worked client side. the pptpd status shows 
" pptpd dead but subsys locked ".

how to solve the problem. i removed the file present in the /var/lock/subsys/pptpd

but still again same problem / pptp not connecting on client side.

my iptables rules

```
[root@server2 ~]# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     gre  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

in pptp config file("/etc/pptpd.conf")
i used this unused IP:

```
localip 10.22.22.1
remoteip 10.22.22.22-222
```

Comment: still not solved the problem..please help guys

Comment: how to solve the problem. i removed the file present in the /var/lock/subsys/pptpd， service pptpd start Startting down pptpd: [FAILED]

Answer (score -1):

```
rm -r /var/lock/subsys/pptpd
service pptpd start
```

It should work

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP stated that he/she had already tried removing the lockfile. If the solution suggested in the answer is different from what the OP already tried, explain _how_ it is different. Besides, blindly removing lockfiles without addressing the underlying cause can be be dangerous, as the lockfiles exist for a reason, the reason usually being avoiding race conditions or conflicts which might lead to inconsistent states.